# Omega 3.x base theme missing after Drupal upgrade

Tags: theming

After upgrading Drupal to 7.4.3, i am missing my Omega 3.x base theme in the ui. My subtheme is still present, but the layout is all messed up. Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put your base theme?

It should be in the same folder as your theme "sites/all/themes". If you put it in the top themes folder, beside Bartik, Seven, etc, it was in the wrong place and this folder is overwritten when you update.

If his is the case you can probably just download it again and put it in the correct folder "sites/all/themes".

Comment: It was added in the sites/all/themes folder, as is my subtheme. Just for testing, when i add the omega 4.x to that same folder, omega 4 shows up in the theme settings page. I also added the files for omega 3 again, but no results there.

Comment: Also important the site was hacked and they forced the Zen base theme to the site, so maybe that has something to do with it, but normally all infected files are removed.